# posix pthreads in c

Tags: multithreading

Iam new to c programming and needs some help.

```
long *taskids[NUM_THREADS];

for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++)
{
  taskids[t] = (long *) malloc(sizeof(long));
 *taskids[t] = t;
  printf("Creating thread %ld\n", t);
  rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *) taskids[t]);
  ...
}
```

This code fragment demonstrates how to pass a simple integer to each thread. The calling thread uses a unique data structure for each thread, insuring that each thread's argument remains intact throughout the program. Iam not able to understand how this is happening can somebody explain it??

Comment: If you are new to C programming, there might be less complex places to start than with pthreads.

Comment: Where did you find this code fragment?

Comment: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#PthreadsAPI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this code is doing is storing an array of pointers to allocated data.  Each thread has space allocated for a long and is then passed a pointer to that value.  This gives the thread a place to work that the main thread still has access to.

This could be done with a little less allocation:

```
long taskids[NUM_THREADS];

for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++)
{
  taskids[t] = t;
  printf("Creating thread %ld\n", t);
  rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *) &taskids[t]);
  ...
}
```

Though this does decrease the flexibility for freeing the taskids.  It also requires that this function doesn't return until all the threads have finished.

Comment: I actually don't like this code.  The requirement that this function not return is fragile.  The original is preferable, since it doesn't have as much potential for failure.

Answer (score 3):

- `malloc` allocates enough memory to hold a long integer. It returns a pointer to long, a `long*`.
- This `long*` is stored into `taskids[t]` so that it can be used later.
- `pthread_create` is called. One of its arguments is a value to be passed to the new thread.

  - Since the `pthread_create` function does not know what kind of value the programmer wants to pass, it uses a `void*` which can be a pointer to anything. `taskids[t]` is the pointer to a long integer. It is cast (that is the `(void *)`) to a void pointer and given as an argument to `pthread_create`.
- `pthread_create` creates a new thread and calls the `PrintHello` function and passes the void pointer to `taskids[t]` as the value to `PrintHello`.
- Once `PrintHello` starts, it will cast the void pointer back to a long pointer and then it can access the long integer that contains its taskid.